# Potentiometer vs PWM for voltage tuning when charging a li-ion battery

Tags: battery-charging, pwm, lithium-ion, potentiometer

Planning to buy a 30V adapter for charging a 7S li-ion (BMS integrated) battery. Need to reduce voltage to 29,4V.

Considering mainly the health of the battery, would an integrated potentiometer be a better solution for charging it than a PWM regulated one? Since with PWM it would peak at 30V and that would not be as good as a steady voltage with a potentiometer?

Is my theory correct?

Comment: The PWM in a charger works through inductances and capacitances to smooth out ripple. Potentiometer has lower efficiency which means a lot more heat. More importantly, do not mess around with charging lithium batteries. Use a proper charger.

Comment: Why would you use a LED driver for charging a battery? A LED driver is not a battery charger. It is not meant to charge batteries. Mishandled lithium batteries may start a fire or explode. Besides LED drivers do what they do to achieve brightness internally, it does not make any difference if you try to set the brightness with a pot or PWM.

Comment: Have you considered buying a proper Li-ion battery charger for charging your batteries and using the LED driver for driving LEDs?

Comment: One notices that 30 V - 29.4 V = 0.6 V which is approximately one diode drop. And yea, don't mess around with Lithium batteries; use a proper charger.

Comment: How cam a LED driver be a balanced Lithium battery charger so that each cell is properly charged? Nothing will detect a full charge (it is not when the voltage reaches 29.4V) and an overcharge will happen when there is nothing to turn off the charger when the battery becomes fully charged.

Comment: @Audioguru. The battery has a BMS, as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: This system uses a LED driver as a charging adapter from factory. I would just swap it out for a new one, since the old one has gone bad. LED driver or not, does not matter much, as long as it outputs the correct voltage. My question was more about potentiometer vs PWM.

Comment: @SalaDus None is the correct answer. Led drivers are not designed to be good chargers. Their voltage can be 5% to 10% different from the spec. They are not designed to always give out a constant voltage, they are designed to drive leds with a constant current always under their maximum voltage, led drivers are not rejected in the factory if they are slightly over voltage, battery charger are designed to fail in a safe matter, led chargers don't have such goal; Be safe and use a adapter designed for charging. A BMS isn't a magic safe your life device